# How to run JBoss TattleTale from inside Gradle build

Tags: gradle, tattletale

I am in love with [JBoss TattleTale](http://tattletale.jboss.org/). Typically, in my Ant builds, I [follow the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/tattletale/userguide/1.1/html_single/#ant) to define the Tattletale tasks and then run them like so:

```
<taskdef name="report"
    classname="org.jboss.tattletale.ant.ReportTask"
    classpathref="tattletale.lib.path.id"/>

...

<tattletale:report source="${src.dir]" destination="${dest.dir}"/>
```

I am now converting my builds over to Gradle and am struggling to figure out how to get Tattletale running in Gradle. There doesn't appear to be a Gradle-Tattletale plugin, and I'm not experienced enough with Gradle to contribute one. But I also know that Gradle can run any Ant plugin and can also executing stuff from the system shell; I'm just not sure how to do this in Gradle because there aren't any docs on this (yet).

So I ask: **How do I run the Tattletale `ReportTask` from inside a Gradle build?**

---

#### Update

Here is what the Gradle/Ant docs show as an example:

```
task loadfile << {
    def files = file('../antLoadfileResources').listFiles().sort()
    files.each { File file ->
        if (file.isFile()) {
            ant.loadfile(srcFile: file, property: file.name)
            println " *** $file.name ***"
            println "${ant.properties[file.name]}"
        }
    }
}
```

However, no where in here do I see how/where to customize this for Tattletale and its `ReportTask`.

Comment: See the "Using Ant from Gradle" chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Answer (score 1):

The following is adapted from https://github.com/roguePanda/tycho-gen/blob/master/build.gradle

It bypasses ant and directly invokes the Tattletale Java class.

It was changed to process a WAR, and mandates a newer javassist in order to handle Java 8 features such as lambdas.

```
configurations {
    tattletale
}

configurations.tattletale {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // other dependencies here...
    tattletale "org.jboss.tattletale:tattletale:1.2.0.Beta2"
}

task createTattletaleProperties {
    ext.props = [reports:"*", enableDot:"true"]
    ext.destFile = new File(buildDir, "tattletale.properties")
    inputs.properties props
    outputs.file destFile
    doLast {
        def properties = new Properties()
        properties.putAll(props)
        destFile.withOutputStream { os ->
            properties.store(os, null)
        }
    }
}

task tattletale(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: [createTattletaleProperties, war]) {
    ext.outputDir = new File(buildDir, "reports/tattletale")
    outputs.dir outputDir
    inputs.files configurations.runtime.files
    inputs.file war.archivePath
    doFirst {
        outputDir.mkdirs()
    }
    main = "org.jboss.tattletale.Main"
    classpath = configurations.tattletale
    systemProperties "jboss-tattletale.properties": createTattletaleProperties.destFile
    args([configurations.runtime.files, war.archivePath].flatten().join("#"))
    args outputDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers either are incomplete or excessively complicated. What I did was use the ant task from gradle which works fine. Let's assume your tattletale jars are beneath rootDir/tools/...

```
ant.taskdef(name: "tattleTaleTask", classname: "org.jboss.tattletale.ant.ReportTask", classpath: "${rootDir}/tools/tattletale-1.1.2.Final/tattletale-ant.jar:${rootDir}/tools/tattletale-1.1.2.Final/tattletale.jar:${rootDir}/tools/tattletale-1.1.2.Final/javassist.jar")
sources = "./src:./src2:./etcetera"
ant.tattleTaleTask(
    source: sources,
    destination: "tattleTaleReport",
    classloader: "org.jboss.tattletale.reporting.classloader.NoopClassLoaderStructure",
    profiles: "java5, java6",
    reports: "*",
    excludes: "notthisjar.jar,notthisjareither.jar,etcetera.jar"
    ){

    }
```

So the above code will generate the report beneath ./tattleTaleReport. It's that simple. The annoyance is that the *source* variable only accepts directories so if there are jars present in those directories you do not wish to scan you need to add them to the *excludes* parameter.